# Help with sum specific elements of a matrix in mathematica

Tags: matrix

I am trying to sum over specific indices in a matrix.

For example, if I have the matrix

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 9}, {1, 5, 9, 7}}
```

i need to sum the index `{2, 1}` and `{4, 3}` , i.e `4 + 9 = 13` automatically.

I try the code

```
Sum[a[[ii]][[jj]], {ii, 2, 4, 2}, {jj, 1, 4 , 2}]
```

and this is equals to 20. (WTF) (i think this shows the result of 4+6+1+9) Why?

In a general form I need to compute the sum of indices `{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {6, 5}, {8, 7}, {10, 9}, {12, 11}, {14,13}, {16,15}` for a 16x16 square matrix.

Thanks for the help

Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 9}, {1, 5, 9, 7}};
positions = {{2, 1}, {4, 3}};
Total@Extract[a, positions]
```

Comment: thanks bro. your answer was useful

Answer (score 7):

To see why it doesn't work as you expected, look at the indices that you generated.

```
Table[{ii, jj}, {ii, 2, 4, 2}, {jj, 1, 4, 2}]

(* {{{2, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 1}, {4, 3}}} *)
```

You generated four indices so the sum was over four entries. Use

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 9}, {1, 5, 9, 7}};

Sum[a[[Sequence @@ i]], {i, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}}}]

(* 13 *)
```

Comment: thanks, now i can understand my problem

Answer (score 6):

I would have used `Extract` if Alan had not posted it first.

So, here is a way to use `Sum`:

```
Sum[a[[## & @@ i]], {i, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}}}]
```

> 13

But that is also posted a minute earlier by Bob Hanlon.

That leaves

```
☺ = {♯, ♯♯} \[Function] +## & @@ (♯[[##]] & @@@ ♯♯);
☺[a, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}}]
```

> 13

and

```
☺☺ = +## & @@ (♯ \[Function] #[[## & @@ ♯]]) /@ #2 &;
☺☺[a, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}}]
```

> 13

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 9}, {1, 5, 9, 7}};
a[[##]] & @@@ Thread@Range[{2, 1}, {4, 3}, 2] // Total
```

> 13

Where you would replace `{4,3}` with `{16,15}` in `Range` for the bigger matrix.

Answer (score 4):

```
a[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ {{2, 1}, {4, 3}} // Total
```

> 13

Answer (score 3):

Just for giggles, and using your $16\times 16$ example:

```
Tr[IdentityMatrix[16][[Range[2 ,16, 2]]].
 Array[C, {16, 16}].
 Transpose[IdentityMatrix[16][[Range[1, 15, 2]]]]]
```

Comment: (I am still stuck on *gedanken Mathematica*, but I believe that ought to work.)

Comment: wow. is beautiful